# How to connect two (or more) BJTs (collector of Q1 to base of Q2 for instance) and still make their bias voltages independent?

Tags: transistors, bjt, bias

The question is in the title. I'm learning about how to use BJTs and was wondering how I could connect them in blocks the way bias voltages (thus operation modes) are not being dependant.

Thank you!

Comment: A capacitor arranged between the two points (output from one to the input of the other) is the most commonly applied tool for this function. The capacitor rapidly charges up to the difference and then simply passes along the AC component with the DC bias "removed." If you feel you need a more detailed answer, I'll try and write one up. But this should be relatively easy to "see."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

A capacitor coupling will do the job easily. The capacitance is chosen to be large such that at DC, the capacitor will be open and the circuits will become independent of each other. Their bias voltages will be independent.

Comment: This figure can be found in the Sedra/Smith textbook, _"Microelectronic Circuits"_. In the 7th edition, it can be found on page 42, figure 1.27.